# Concatenate Issues

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a column based on the other columns but it keeps giving me the error:

"Error Converting varchar to float" I think it is trying to add instead of concatenating.

My statement looks like this:

```
select column1 + ' ' + column2 + ' ' as ColumnDesired
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what are the datatypes on your columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if any of those columns are numeric, it is trying to add due to data type precedence. E.g. `SELECT 4 + 'cow'` is taking `4` and trying to add `cow` to it mathematically, since it tries to convert all expressions to the data type with the highest precedent (in that case, `INT`).

So, use `CONVERT` to make sure that all of your numeric and other non-string data type columns are explicitly treated as strings. I'm guessing 32 characters should be enough for any of these columns, just be careful to not accidentally truncate any columns where there are more than 32 characters.

```
SELECT ColumnDesired = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), column1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), column2)
FROM ...
```

You may also need to deal with `NULL`s

```
SELECT ColumnDesired = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), column1), '')
       + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), column2), '')
FROM ...
```

Comment: This did work,so thank you. But what I don't understand is that I've written Concatenating statements like that before and sql server was ok with it.

Comment: @user1991372 some concatenation sequences will be ok - it's all about the types. Typically if you are presenting data on a web page or in an application though, the concatenation is much safer to do there (you're dealing with individual values instead of a set, and there is no harm at display time in just treating everything as a string).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to concatenate the columns, you might need to convert the one that is a numeric:

```
select cast(column1 as varchar(50)) + ' ' + column2 + ' ' as ColumnDesired
```

or

```
select column1 + ' ' +  cast(column2 as varchar(50)) + ' ' as ColumnDesired
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the columns is numeric, use CONVERT().

Bottomline, never rely on implicit conversion, and CONVERT() all non-(N)CHAR/(N)VARCHAR values.

Comment: That explains it. It must usually use implicit conversion.